# The Poincare Plane distance

Tags: geometry

The Poincare plane, $\mathbb{H}$, is:

$$\mathbb{H} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \ | \ y>0\}$$
$$_{a}L = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{H} \ | \ x=a\}$$
$$_{c}L_r = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{H} \ | \ (x-c)^2+y^2=r^2\}.$$

The Poincare distance is given by the following if $x_1=x_2$:

$$d_\mathbb{H}(P,Q)=|ln(y_2/y_1)|$$

---

My question is, why isn't the distance just $$d_\mathbb{H}(P,Q)=|y_2-y_1|$$ instead since $x_1=x_2$? Why is the natural logarithm introduced for the distance?

Comment: The formula comes from the general definition of the line element, $ds^2 = (dx^2 + dy^2)/y^2$. The distance function isn't arbitrary; it's chosen to make the resulting space negatively curved, and it has a very nice isometry group. If you just take the Euclidean distance on $\mathbb{H}$, the resulting space is flat, and it's not even complete: consider the case $y_i \to 0$.

Comment: @anomaly hmm I have not yet covered isometry nor calculus in the book. Is there a different approach in understanding why without introducing isometry or calculus?